# Error when parsing header with cookies in Java7

Tags: java, web-services, java-7, java-metro-framework

I am connecting to a web service using Metro Library. It is working fine in Java6.

When I ran the same code in Java7 (Update 15), I was getting a null pointer exception when HttpSoapConnection class is parsing the post message response which contains cookie.

When I debugged, I was getting **value** as **"Null"** whenever the **key** is **“Set-Cookie”**.
I could not further debug “httpConnection.getHeaderFiedl(i)” as **“HttpUrlConnection”** class is in Java7 Runtime.

I am getting this problem in Java7 only.

Code Snippet where I am getting **“Null”** value in post method of **HttpSoapConnection** class.

```
// Header field 0 is the status line so we skip it.
int i = 1;
while (true) {
  key = httpConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
  value = httpConnection.getHeaderField(i); //I am getting Null value when key is "set-cookie"
  if (key == null && value == null)
         break;
  if (key != null) {
         StringTokenizer values =
         new StringTokenizer(value, ",");
          while (values.hasMoreTokens())
          headers.addHeader(key, values.nextToken().trim());
  }
  i++;
}
```

**Soap Response Header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 3006
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ReqClientId=5e1a2136-2f85-4a41-954e-67380037e91c; expires=Sun, 24-Jun-2063 12:26:57 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2013 12:26:57 GMT
```